# textContent/innerText/innerHTML in angular binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12, angular-ivy

I'm trying to prevent content replacing for angular app in my custom component, it happening when on custom component like `<my-component></my-component>` placed BOUNDED property `textContent/innerHTML/innerText`, e.g. `<my-component [textContent]="example"></my-component>` and my component just dying without message.
as i know for now angular aplying content replacing with bounded defualt propertys in the moment afterViewInit in the same moment where it apply interpolation it means i can't split them by checking something like `elementRef.nativeElement.textContent/innerHTML/innerText` in the afterViewInit(or any else).

also i can't get it by `getAtribute/hasAtribute` you will got null/false if you will try to do this on bounded `textContent/innerHTML/innerText` **(maybe it's bug idk can some one answer for that pls)**
so for now i have two main idea how can i do this

1. i can check some unique element with BEM notation still exist inside my component in afterViewInit but it's to local.
2. i can catch bounded property by input field with the same name as property but it's to dirty even if i need check only one but i wanna check them all(3).
3. (my senior colleague prompted me) i can check `elementRef.nativeElement.children !== 0` that looks good but we will be ignore `innerHTML` with elements inside

maybe you have better idea how i can to do this
i use angular 12 with ivy mod and i was't test it on other version

Comment: Can’t you just create a directive with the same selector [textContent] that also has the same @Input? Or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: i think i can do this but it's looking more dirty than i just define input(s) inside my component like @Input textContent and checking them to be undefined e.g. in onInit, i just trying to do this better than i have now

Comment: Please post your `<my-comopnent/>` code.

Comment: Right. I’m not sure why it’s dirty, but I’d go for option 2 and just add 3 Inputs. Unless.. you could check something like contentChildren - but unsure if that yields anything.